# How to join two result sets from same table with different conditions on same column?

Tags: mysql

```
select * from unit_of_measure;
+--------+-----------+--------+------------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+---------------+------------------+
| uom_id | uom_name  | symbol | created_by | created_date | created_ip_addr | modified_by | modified_date | modified_ip_addr |
+--------+-----------+--------+------------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+---------------+------------------+
|      1 | number    | NULL   | NULL       | NULL         | NULL            | NULL        | NULL          | NULL             |
|      2 | kilograms | NULL   | NULL       | NULL         | NULL            | NULL        | NULL          | NULL             |
|      3 | liters    | NULL   | NULL       | NULL         | NULL            | NULL        | NULL          | NULL             |
+--------+-----------+--------+------------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+---------------+------------------+
```

From this table I am trying to combine two result sets like:

```
select uom_name as uomname1 from unit_of_measure where uom_id=1;

select uom_name as uomname2 from unit_of_measure where uom_id=2;
```

Can anyone help me to join these two result sets. I have tried with union but it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you want `number` and `kilograms` to appear as a single column (comma separated), do this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(uom_name) UnitsOfMeasure
FROM unit_of_measure WHERE uom_id IN (1,2);
```

If you want `number` and `kilograms` to appear as a single column (space separated), do this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(uom_name SEPARATOR ' ') UnitsOfMeasure
FROM unit_of_measure WHERE uom_id IN (1,2);
```

If you want `number` and `kilograms` to appear as separate columns, do this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT uom_name AS uomname1 FROM unit_of_measure WHERE uom_id=1) A,
(SELECT uom_name AS uomname2 FROM unit_of_measure WHERE uom_id=2) B;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 0):

**Try his code :**

```
  select u1.uom_name as uomname1 
    from unit_of_measure  as u1 inner join unit_of_measure  as u2
     on u1.uom_id=u2.uom_id
     where u1.uom_id=1 
    ans u2.uom_id;
```

But you can get the same result with :

```
select uom_name from unit_of_measure where uom_id in (1,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

RolandoMySQLDBA already covered most of it. Here's an alternative to his third suggestion:

```
select max(uomname1) as uomname1
     , max(uomname2) as uomname2
from (
    select case when uom_id=1 then uom_name end as uomname1
         , case when uom_id=2 then uom_name end as uomname2
    from unit_of_measure
    where uom_id IN (1,2)
) as x;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use UNION clause between them:

```
SELECT uom_name AS uomname1 FROM unit_of_measure WHERE uom_id=1
 UNION
SELECT uom_name AS uomname2 FROM unit_of_measure WHERE uom_id=2
```